# How to get the Document name in this LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, group-by

Below is my LINQ

```
  IQueryable<DocumentMapper> query = (from c in entities.tTOCStructures
                                                    join e in entities.tUsers on c.CreatedBy equals e.UserUID
                                                    group c by c.FolderID into docs
                                                    where documentIds.Contains(docs.Key) 
                                                    select new DocumentMapper()
                                                    {
                                                         //DocumentName = Document Name
                                                        //Owner = e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName,
                                                        Editors = (from f in entities.tUsers join g in entities.tCheckoutViewUsers on f.UserUID equals g.ViewUserid where g.IsEditor == true && documentIds.Contains(g.DocumentID) select (f.FirstName + " " + f.LastName)),
                                                        Approvers = (from f in entities.tUsers join g in entities.tCheckoutViewUsers on f.UserUID equals g.ViewUserid where g.IsApprover == true && documentIds.Contains(g.DocumentID) select (f.FirstName + " " + f.LastName)),
                                                        Reviewers = (from f in entities.tUsers join g in entities.tCheckoutViewUsers on f.UserUID equals g.ViewUserid where g.IsReviewer == true && documentIds.Contains(g.DocumentID) select (f.FirstName + " " + f.LastName))
                                                    });
                documents = query.ToList<DocumentMapper>();
```

How do I get the document name & Owner in the above LINQ.

The Relationship is as below:-

> *One Document will have one  Document Name & Owner but multiple Editors, Approves, Reviewers.*

Class:-

```
 public class DocumentMapper
{
    public string DocumentName { get; set; }

    public string Owner { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> Editors { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> Reviewers { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> Approvers { get; set; }

}
```

If any suggestion on improving this LINQ , would love to hear

Comment: Without seeing your models it is not really possible to help you. One thing i can tell is that your subqueries for Editors/Approvers/Reviewers will be severely inefficient.

Comment: @zaitsman, can you please tell how can I improve that??

Comment: @zaitsman , I have addded Model

Comment: (1) Model means the entity classes, not the resulting class. (2) It's really hard to figure out what are you trying to achieve because the `select` part of the query has nothing in common with (does not use) the previous part (`join`, `group by`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm rather guessing, but following your code, you might want to make select and take first item. I cannot help more unless, (as statet above) you provide more code.

```
DocumentName = ((from f in entities.tUsers join g in entities.tCheckoutViewUsers on f.UserUID equals g.ViewUserid where g.IsEditor == true && documentIds.Contains(g.DocumentID) select (g.DocumentName)).First(),
```

Comment: I already tried with this & it returns the document name as well but some month back I was requiring similar query but I did it using the `documents.Key` as its ONE TO ONE relationship